# Move voice chat users using Discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to program a bot that, following a command, moves a user to a room a number of times of your choice.
For configuration and hosting I am using autocode.com, both "userId" and "number" are set correctly.
However, the user is not moved away.
This is the code

```
const lib = require('lib')({token: process.env.STDLIB_SECRET_TOKEN});

let isAdmin = (context.params.event.member.permissions & (1<<3)) === (1<<3);

if (isAdmin) {
  let userId = context.params.event.data.options[0].value;
  let number = context.params.event.data.options[1].value;
  
  let result = await lib.discord.channels['@0.1.0'].messages.create({
    channel_id: `${context.params.event.channel_id}`,
    content: `It's time to Jump for ` +number+ ' times'
  });
  for(let i = 0; i < number; i++){
  await guild.member(userId).voice.setChannel("789946095341535242");
  await sleep(1000)}
} else {
  await lib.discord.channels['@0.1.0'].messages.create({
    channel_id: `${context.params.event.channel_id}`,
    content: `This command is admin only!`,
  });
}
```

I think the problem is at
`await guild.member (userId) .voice.setChannel ("789946095341535242");` 
but I can't solve the problem, does anyone know what the problem could be and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm baffled that you're using template strings and then completely missing the point of them. Hint: `Jump for ${number} times`.

Comment: Tip: `x & (1 << 3) == (1 << 3)` is redundant. When checking a single bit `x & (1 << 3)` is sufficient. It will either be zero (false) or non-zero (true).

Comment: If I have to be honest, this line here:
```let isAdmin = (context.params.event.member.permissions & (1 << 3)) === (1 << 3);``` I copied it and did not fully understand its meaning. but I assumed that it evades checking user permissions in the first part and that ```(1 << 3)) === (1 << 3)``` is some sort of control string..
This is my first experience with JS so I still don't get along very well, using $ {variable} will then get the contents of the variable, right?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: It's not some dark mystery, it's just a [bitmask test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)). Based on reading that it looks like the "admin bit" is in position 3, here [documented as `ADMINISTRATOR`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/permissions).

Comment: The use of `${...}` is documented in [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Yes I had this error https://pastebin.com/fMdmCCks but I assume that the problem is not this as the error I think goes to say that the ID of the channel is wrong but I assume it is because having loaded it on autocode it cannot know the validity of the room ID

Comment: Thanks Tadman, now I'm going to read the two documents you sent me, for the other problem do you have any ideas? Searching online I had also seen ```userId.voice.setChannel ("789946095341535242") ``` but it still gives problems